# MongoDB permission to view collections not working

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 dbs:

- admin
- ops

I have a user with a `readWriteAnyDatabase` role but he cannot list the collections in the `ops` db.

I have another user with a `root` role and he succeeded in listing the collections for the `ops` db.

I try to view the collections in `ops`

The error I am getting:

> Not authorized to execute command: listCollections...

using mongodb: 3.4.7

In the mongoDB config I only added `auto=true`.

What can be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give that "readWriteAnyDatabase" role to the user for "admin" database.

```
use admin
db.createUser({user:"test", pwd:"test", roles: ["readWriteAnyDatabase"]})
```

after that you can login with that user and see all collections

```
mongo -u test -p test --authenticationDatabase admin opt
Mongo> db
opt
Mongo> show collections
test_collection
Mongo>
```